# Хост 'my ip' не имеет права подключаться к этому серверу MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, хостинг, vps

Вообщем я создал MySQL на хостинге задал ему IP моего vps сервера дал логин и пароль, потом через программу navicat создал БД и в своем проекте указал коннект к моем MySQL серверу через метод UseMySql указал логин и пароль всё как надо. Запускаю проект через VS всё работает, но если  я комплю свой проект на хостинг выводится ошибка, которая в заголовке вопроса.

Comment: 1) Не оставляйте базу открытой во внешний интернет, это черевато. Подключайтесь к ней через localhost, если база и программа на одном сервере. 2) У вас где то не верно заданы права на подключение к базе.

Comment: @ГеннадийП насчёт прав подключения к базе можно по подробнее, что мне сделать чтобы мой проект когда я его запускаю на хостинг мог пользоваться БД  и записывать туда значения

Comment: Беглое гугление [вот что нашло](https://dev58.ru/articles/nastrojka_udalennogo_dostupa_k_MySql)

Comment: @aepot mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; то етсь надо эту штуку прописать чтобы когда я компилил своего бота на хост значения могли записываться в бд

Comment: @whitetears я не разбираюсь в MySQL. Я просто поискал.